# How can I analyse instagram pictures?

Tags: dataset, computer-vision, instagram, social-networking, instagram-api

I ve the task to crowd and analyse a set of instagram users's posts, including texts and pictures. I don t need to know the user identity.
In particular, I ve to use the images to train some machine learning classifier/regressor. So that I need to temporaly store the picture to extract visual features.
Reading the [instagram API policy](https://www.instagram.com/about/legal/terms/api/) I m a bit confused :

11. Comply with any requirements or restrictions imposed on usage of Instagram user photos and videos ("User Content") by their respective owners. You are solely responsible for making use of User Content in compliance with owners' requirements or restrictions.

14 only store or cache User Content for the period necessary to provide your app's service.

17.Don't apply computer vision technology to User Content, without our prior permission

11 => what are the common owner's restrictions? I mean, when people post a picture on instagram do they set any restriction or are they publicly available? And then there are some cases of pictures with restrictions

14 => i have not to build or sell any app. I need to store the pictures just the time needed for the analysis. However, according to this point I could store pictures on a drive and than remove them when finished. Did I get the point or I m wrong?

17 => I guess that this point is related to image manipulation. Not analysis.

I hope that someone can clarify me what can I do, considering my purpose. As an example, at [this](http://mm.doshisha.ac.jp/en/senti/CrossSentiment.html) page you can see a project in which a set of instagram picture have been crowled, labelled and analysed. The downloadable file doesn t contain the pictures, but just their instagram ids.

Comment: This topic really isn't within the scope of Stack Overflow.  Interpreting the finer points of a EULA is probably best left to a lawyer.

Comment: I imagine that there are a lot of scientists in stackoverflow both interested and experienced with such topics. For this reason i posted this question here.